# Inject module into controller AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have two AngularJs Modules, one is my app the other is a list of constants.  I want to inject the constant module into my app module and use the constants inside my controllers.  I have been able to achieve this inside a factory but I can't access my constants inside my controller.

app module:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myapp', [
            'constants',
            'ngMaterial',
            'ngCordova',
            'ngStorage',
            'relativeDate',
            'ui.router',
            'myapp.services.myservice'
            ])
```

constant module:

```
angular.module('constants', [])

.constant('appName', 'mynewapp');
```

In my factory where I can access my constants:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myapp.services.myservice', [])

        .factory('Myservice', function ($http, appName) {
           console.log(appName); //works great!
```

My controller where I CANNOT access constants

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myapp')
        .controller('MyController', [
            '$cordovaOauth',
            '$state',
            '$rootScope',
            'Myservice',
            MyController
        ]);

    function MyController($cordovaOauth, $state, $rootScope, Myservice, appName ) {
            console.log(appName); //undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to declare dependency injection token for `appName` constant:

```
.controller('MyController', [
    '$cordovaOauth',
    '$state',
    '$rootScope',
    'Myservice',
    'appName',  // <---- don't forget me
    MyController
]);
```

Comment: Don't forget to approve good answers, especially when it is clearly the right answer, and others can't make a better answer.